# Returning variable from method

Tags: variables, methods, return

```
for(Element synonym: Words){
            synonyms.add(synonym);
        }
        return synonyms.get(7);
        }
```

i am retrieving an unknown amount of words every time i add a synonym to the synonyms list, so if i try access a portion of the list that doesnt exist (eg. element 7 when there are only 3), i get an index out of bounds error, how can i check to see if the element exists and if it doesn't, return something else?

i have tried checking to see if there is an element or not but i dont know how

Comment: please add a tag indication which language is this.

Comment: Get the size of arraylist. If the index is greater than or equal to size. Then it is not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer would be to check for the length of the array for the index that you want to return. If it exists, return that, otherwise do something else.

```
 return synonyms.length == 7 ? synonyms.get(7) : somethingElse;
```